# Declaration missing http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

Tags: xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I have a xslt1.0 mapping file that looks like this at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s0="http://F.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" exclude-result-prefixes="s0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="groupbyproduct" match="Products" use="product"/>
    <xsl:template match="/s0:Product">
        <enfinity xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" family="enfinity" branch="enterprise" build="build">
```

When I use BizTalk in Visual Studio to create an xml file from a csv, the declaration at the top looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enfinity xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" major="6" minor="1" family="enfinity" branch="enterprise" build="build" xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt">
```

I don't think the order matters particuarly, but it is definitely missing this line within <enfinity

```
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
```

How do I ensure this is included please?

Comment: That prefix `xml` is always bound to that namespace so I think and XSLT processor or any serializer can omit it.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, does that mean it makes no difference to the overall xml output file even though it's not shown?

Comment: Correct. This namespace declaration would serve no useful purpose, it would be totally redundant

Comment: In my view any XML parser should be able to deal with `xml` prefixed attributes like `xml:lang` even if the source document does not declare that prefix.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I see, in case my customer insists that it should be there for their peace of mind, is it easy to tweak either the mapping file or the schema file so it does appear?

Comment: I saw the question because of the XSLT tag, I would think that XSLT processors are free to omit that `xml` prefix declaration as it is not needed. Whether there is a way to ensure it is output nevertheless, I am not sure at the moment, would need to check the spec or processor documentation details. As for Biztalk mapping or schema files, sorry, I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Can you please add at least the minimum code to reproduce, e.g a small XSLT file, schema file, map that uses that XSLT and XML sample file?  As well as a sample XML file of what you are getting and one that shows what you expect.